# Ошибка при удалении элемента в deque через итератор

Tags: c++, сортировка, итераторы

myDeque.erase(min) выдает ошибку: cannot seek value-initialized deque iterator

```
void sort(deque<int> &myDeque)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myDeque.size(); i++)
    {
        auto currentPosition = myDeque.begin() + i;
        auto min = currentPosition;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < myDeque.size(); j++)
        {
            if (*min > *currentPosition)
            {
                min = currentPosition;
            }
            currentPosition++;
        }
        myDeque.push_front(*min);
        myDeque.erase(min);
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `push_front` в `std::deque` инвалидирует *все* итераторы данного контейнера. В том числе ваш `min`. По этой причине вызов

```
myDeque.erase(min);
```

приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Сначала делайте `erase`, а уж потом `push_front`, предварительно сохраняя значение.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, вы таким странным образом пытаетесь сортировать контейнер `std::deque` по убыванию значений.

Во-первых, у вас имеется логическая ошибка.

Внутри этого цикла

```
    for (int j = i + 1; j < myDeque.size(); j++)
    {
        if (*min > *currentPosition)
        {
            min = currentPosition;
        }
        currentPosition++;
    }
```

значение итератора `currentPosition` должно в начале цикла быть рано `min + 1`, а не `min`, как это у вас имеет место.

```
auto currentPosition = myDeque.begin() + i;
auto min = currentPosition;
```

В результате у вас последний элемент контейнера не рассматривается в этом цикле.

То есть должно быть по крайней мере так

```
auto min = myDeque.begin() + i;
auto currentPosition = min + 1;
```

так как переменная `j` начинается с `i + 1` в цикле.

```
    for (int j = i + 1; j < myDeque.size(); j++)
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Во-вторых, после этого предложения

```
    myDeque.push_front(*min);
```

Итератор `min` становится недействительным.

Ваша функция может выглядеть, к примеру, следующим образом. Я не думаю, что стоит ограничиваться только контейнером `std::deque` с целочисленными значениями. Поэтому я объявил функцию шаблонной и назвал ее `sort_descending`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <deque>

template <typename T>
void sort_descending( std::deque<T> &myDeque )
{
    for ( typename std::deque<T>::size_type i = 0; i < myDeque.size(); i++ )
    {
        auto min = std::next( std::begin( myDeque ), i );
        for ( auto current = std::next( min ); current != std::end( myDeque ); ++current )
        {
            if ( *current < *min ) min = current;
        }

        auto value = *min;
        myDeque.erase( min );
        myDeque.push_front( value );
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::deque<int> myDeque = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( const auto &item : myDeque ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    sort_descending( myDeque );

    for ( const auto &item : myDeque ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Нешаблонная функция (если именно такая вам нужна) не сильно отличается от шаблонной.

```
void sort_descending( std::deque<int> &myDeque )
{
    for ( std::deque<int>::size_type i = 0; i < myDeque.size(); i++ )
    {
        auto min = std::next( std::begin( myDeque ), i );
        for ( auto current = std::next( min ); current != std::end( myDeque ); ++current )
        {
            if ( *current < *min ) min = current;
        }

        auto value = *min;
        myDeque.erase( min );
        myDeque.push_front( value );
    }
}
```